# What's the meaning of these points in $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{xy}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to find the critical points of $f:\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid xy \neq 0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + \frac{1}{xy}$

Then I made $ \nabla f(x,y)=(0,0) $ and obtained the points $P_1 = (2^{-1/4},2^{-1/4})$ and $P_2=(-2^{-1/4},-2^{-1/4})$

But when I looked at the graph of $f$,

[image]

I saw that the points I obtained indeed look like local extremal points, but the points $P_3 = (2^{-1/4},-2^{-1/4})$ and $P_4 = (-2^{-1/4},2^{-1/4})$ are points that look like saddle points, but if they were saddle points, then $\nabla f(P_3)$ and $\nabla f(P_4)$ should be $(0,0)$, which doesn't happen. I want to understand why they look like this and if they have a special meaning for the function $f$.

Comment: It is hard to see with bare eyes if the tangent space to the graph of $f$ at the four points is - in each one - parallel to $Oxy$ or not. This means to "see"that locally the colors do not become dark in any direction.

Comment: Then I may conclude that in those points the tangent space isn't parallel to $Oxy$ but make a "small" angle with it to look that way in the graph?

Comment: Yes, for instance sage computes via `sage: a = 2^(-1/4); (x^2+y^2+1/x/y).gradient()(a,-a)` the gradient in that point to be `(2*2^(3/4), -2*2^(3/4))`. A plot of the function in the immediate neighborhood of this point will have better chances to use the colors and make the difference sensible for the eye...